# Is there an gcc/Xcode pragma to suppress warnings?

Tags: xcode, gcc, pragma, gcc-warning

Is there a `#pragma` to have gcc/Xcode suppress specific warnings, similar to Java's `@SuppressWarning` annotation?

I compile with `-Wall` as a rule, but there are some situations where I'd like to just ignore a specific warning (e.g. while writing some quick/dirty code just to help debug something).

I'm not looking for "fix the code" answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's a viable solution](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.1/cpp/System-Headers.html#System-Headers). Use `#pragma GCC system_header` to let GCC handle your code in a very special way, thus suppressing any non fatal `#warning`.

Remeber you're just fooling your preprocessor, not the real compiler. Suppressing warnings could be harmful most of times.

Comment: In an ideal world, we should even trat all warning as errors (using -Werror). That's what I do whenever I can. It becomes hard when dealing with multiple platforms, but other than that, warning = error.

Comment: Yep, I do -Werror as well. My question was more for temporary code to aid debugging.

Comment: Too bad you can't do this in a block. Doing it for rest of file is too dangerous for me.

Answer (score 2):

In gcc4.6 and later you can use pragma's to suppress specific warnings and do that suppression only to a specific block of code, i.e. :

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic 
push #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations" 
// Code that causes warning goes here
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

The push/pop are used to preserve the diagnostic options that were in place before your code was processed.

This would be a much better approach than using "`#pragma GCC system_header`" to suppress all warnings. (Of course, in older gcc you may be "stuck" with the `#pragma GCC system_header` approach!)

Here's a nice reference on suppressing gcc warnings:
http://www.dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/SuppressingGCCWarnings.html

This page also describes how to use `-fdiagnostics-show-option` to find out what option controls a particular warning.

Of course, as others mention, it's generally far preferable to fix the root cause of all warnings than to suppress them! However, sometimes that is not possible.